# PHP nested loops - get production order ready date according to weekly available hours

Tags: mysql, loops, nested, composer-php

I have struggled with this for days without success :( 
I have a production order list with orders which need certain amount of hours to finish.

Then I have a separate table with weekly available hours, e.g w52/2018 - 340h.

I need to loop through order rows and weekly available hours and calculate ready date for every order row.

Inside the code, comments with capital letters are the issues I'm struggling with. And there might be other things also totally wrong.

```php
 $year = date("Y");
 $week = date("W");

 //outer loop query - loops through production order rows (every row has 
 production time hours needed for the row)
 $db->setQuery("
SELECT a.*
  FROM work_orders AS a 
 ORDER 
    BY a.id ASC
");
 $results_work_order = $db->loadObjectList();

 //inner loop query (loops through weeks database table where weekly 
 available production hours are retrieved)
 $db->setQuery("SELECT a.work_hours_per_week FROM work_schedule AS a 
 WHERE a.year >= " .$year ." AND a.week >= " . $week ." ORDER BY a.year, 
 a.week ASC");  
 $results_work_hours = $db->loadObjectList();


 foreach ($results_work_order as $result_work_order) {

foreach ($results_work_hours as $result_work_hours) {

//gets the amount of hours needed to complete the order
$work_order_hours_left = $result_work_order->work_order_hours_left;

//gets weekly available hours starting from current week
$weekly_hours = $result_work_hours->work_hours_per_week;


//if weekly available hour are greater than hours needed for current order row...
if($weekly_hours > $work_order_hours_left) {

    //gets ready weekday: divides current row hours with weekly hours and rounds (e.g. 150 / 330 = 0.45), 0.45 * 7 = 3.15, rounded up = 4 = Thursday
    $ready_weekday = roundup(($work_order_hours_left / $weekly_hours) * 7), 0)

    //HOW TO GET DATE FOR THE WEEK/YEAR's THURSDAY (CALCULATED READY DATE)
    $calculated_ready_date=???

    //updates the production order row's calculated ready date
    $db->setQuery("UPDATE work_orders SET calc_ready_date  = " . $db->Quote($calculated_ready_date) . " 
    WHERE id = " . $db->Quote($result_outer->id));
    $db->query();

    //SHOULD CONTINUE TO NEXT OUTER LOOP AND KEEP THE HOURS LEFT FROM THIS WEEK TO NEXT PRODUCTION ORDER ROW
    //NEXT INNER LOOP SHOULD CONTINUE WHERE IT LAST LEFT OFF 


    } else {
    //weekly available hours are smaller than hours needed for current production order row

    //SHOULD GET THE WEEKLY HOURS FROM PREVIOUS WEEK AND ADD HOURS FROM CURRENT WEEK, THEN CHECK IF THESE ARE ENOUGH TO FINISH CURRENT PRODCUTION ORDER
    //GETS THE READY DATE SIMILAR WAY AS IF THE CODE BEFORE "ELSE" ??? HOW???

       }

    }

}
```

I would be extremely grateful for any help guiding me to the right track.

Thanks!
Laura

Answer (score 0):

To get the date from a week number and year

```
$calculated_ready_date = date( "l, M jS, Y", strtotime($year."W".sprintf("%02u", $week)."1") );
```

In this case you get the first day of that week. you can change the number 1 tot 7 tot get the last day of the week.

You can use break to end the inner loop or continue to go on with the next item.

Comment: Thanks! But how can I continue the next inner loop where it last break.

Comment: if you break it will go on with the next item from the outer loop. Use continue to go on with the inner loop (next item)